# dnscrypt-proxy not working after changing default server

Tags: proxy, dns

I've installed dnscrypt-proxy form repos on Ubuntu 16.10, than I tested it against command:

```
dig txt debug.opendns.com
```

And got what I needed:

dig txt debug.opendns.com

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> txt debug.opendns.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 48435
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 6, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;debug.opendns.com.     IN  TXT

;; ANSWER SECTION:
debug.opendns.com.  0   IN  TXT "server m1.hkg"
debug.opendns.com.  0   IN  TXT "flags 20 0 70 7950800000000000000"
debug.opendns.com.  0   IN  TXT "originid 0"
debug.opendns.com.  0   IN  TXT "actype 0"
debug.opendns.com.  0   IN  TXT "source 31.192.111.175:43228"
debug.opendns.com.  0   IN  TXT "**dnscrypt enabled** (717473654A614970)"

;; Query time: 279 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.2.1#53(127.0.2.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Feb 20 18:18:24 CET 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 250
```

"dnscrypt enabled" so it's working.
Than I wanted to change opends server to a different one. 
So at: /etc/default/dncrypt-proxy

I set:

```
DNSCRYPT_PROXY_RESOLVER_NAME=ns0.dnscrypt.is
```

And now I see no "dnscrypt enabled":

```
dig txt debug.opendns.com
;; Truncated, retrying in TCP mode.

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> txt debug.opendns.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 44963
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;debug.opendns.com.     IN  TXT

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
opendns.com.        2077    IN  SOA auth1.opendns.com. noc.opendns.com. 1487092083 16384 2048 1048576 2560

;; Query time: 442 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.2.1#53(127.0.2.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Feb 20 18:23:51 CET 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 92
```

Website https://dnsleaktest.com/ confirms that I'm using **93-95-228-87.1984.is** server.

Why there's no "dnscrypt enabled"?

I my DNS encrypted?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's working as it should be and it's normal behaviour. Andrew gave me an answer:

http://www.webupd8.org/2014/08/encrypt-dns-traffic-in-ubuntu-with.html#comment-3165943154